# "Ignis solis propinqui"

Tags: lingua-latina-per-se-illustrata, grammar-choice

*Linguā Latīnā Per Sē Illūstrātā* Ioānnis Ørbergī pāginā 207 scrīptum est:

> Ignis sōlis propinquī cēram, quā pennae iūnctae et fīxae erant, mollīvit et pennās ussit.

Cur nōn "propinquus" dīcit?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's agreeing with *sōlis*, gen. sg. m.

Comment: Well, that clears it up: "the fires of the nearby Sun" rather than "the nearby fires of the Sun". I was thrown by the way _-is_ is both nominative and genitive. Does resolving this kind of ambiguity ever get easy enough that you don't have to think about it?

Comment: @BenKovitz, yes, it actually does!